# delete intersecting values in an arraylist

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a class like this

```
    public class Func {
    String id;
    long startTime;
    long endTime;
}
```

and in one of the methods I have list of these class objects

```
List<Func> funList = new ArrayList<Func>();
```

Whats the best way to remove the objects from this funList whose startTime and endTime intersect with another object in the same list.

One way I can think of is to take each object in the list and compare with other objects and put the id in an other data structure if it intersects. After every object is compared against other, go through the datastructure where ID's are save and remove them from the List.

Comment: Just to clarify: if two objects' `startTime` and `endTime` intersect (overlap), then you want to remove *both* of them from `funList`?

Comment: Yes I want to delete both

Comment: Are they in any particular order?  Can you do intersection check as you add a new value?  There is the obvious bruteforce O(n^2) option with an iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sort by startTime descending, endTime acsending.
2. Scan array from left to right holding element with currently max right end/

   1. If new item's left end is less than current max right then mark both for deletion.
   2. Update maximum right if needed.

Complexity: `O(n ln n)`

**EDIT example**:

1. (1, 3) (2, 4) (5, 6)
2. curmax = -inf
3. curmax = 3
4. 2 < 3 - mark first and second as "bad". curmax = 4
5. 5 > 4 - do nothing. curmax = 6.
6. (5,6) - is the only good segment.

Comment: I didn't follow the 2nd step. Can you elaborate that.

Answer (score 1):

If your funList is small, you can simply compare each item with each other item in `O(n*n)` time, checking for overlaps. for each pair of items `a` and `b`, they overlap if `a.startTime < b.endTime && b.startTime < a.endTime`.

Otherwise, with many items you want an `O(nlg(n))` algorithm. kilotaras' answer works, but implementing it can be tricky; you probably want to have `Func` extend `Comparable` and define a `compareTo` function to make sorting easier and to make the code clearer to read.

Comment: So first you sort your list of Func objects by their `startTime`. Once your list is sorted, keep track of the Func object with the largest `endTime`, initializing it with the first item: `Func lastEndItem = funList.get(0)`. Now, loop through the other items. Note that while looking at item `x`, since our `lastEndItem` is some item before `x`, the only way `x` could overlap something is if `lastEndItem.endTime > x.startTime` ( if it doesn't overlap with lastEndItem, it can't possibly overlap with things before lastEndItem, since funList is sorted. ) Remember to update lastEndItem if needed!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Use a Set so that its elements are distinct.
Set<Func> funcsToRemove = new HashSet<Func>();
for (Func f1 : funList)
{
    for (Func f2 : funList)
    {
        // If the time intervals of f1 and f2 overlap, then remove both of them.
        if ((f2.startTime >= f1.startTime && f2.startTime <= f2.endTime) ||
            (f2.endTime >= f1.startTime && f2.endTime <= f2.endTime))
        {
            funcsToRemove.add(f1);
            funcsToRemove.add(f2);
        }
    }
}
for (Func toRemove : funcsToRemove)
    funlist.remove(toRemove);
```

Comment: I believe you can avoid that last loop using an `Iterator` and removing in the two nested loops above

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc Yes, that's true. I just think that code using this "smart" `for` loop is more clear than code using `Iterator`s.