# resolve intersecting values in arraylist

Tags: java, algorithm

```
public class IDS{
    public String id;
    public long startTime;
    public long endTime;
}

List<IDS> existingIDS = new ArrayList<IDS>();
List<IDS> newIDSToWrite = new ArrayList<IDS>();
```

I want to merge the `newIDSToWrite` values with `existingIDS` values, with `newIDSToWrite` values taking precedence if a conflict occurs.

`existingIDS` has values like this `(id1,4,7) (id2,10,14) (id3,16,21)`

`newIDSToWrite` has values like this `(id4,1,5) (id5,8,9) (id6,12,15) (id7,18,20)`

If the `newIDSToWrite` above is merged with `existingIDS` result should be like `(id4,1,5) (id1,5,7)  (id5,8,9) (id2,10,12) (id6,12,15) (id3,16,18) (id7,18,20) (id3,20,21)`

Whats the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method `List.retainAll()`:

```
existingIDS.retainAll(newIDSToWrite);
```

Link to the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)).

**UPDATE:**
Good comment by dasblinkenlight: in class ID you should override `hash()` and `equals()` methods in order to achieve a correct behavior (two IDs that are created with the same values should be equal even if they don't point to the same object in the heap).

Comment: retainAll doensn't work in the case of an overlap of time intervals.

Comment: @vjk in case you want to handle that case - you'll have to "manually" handle it by writing your own "merge" method.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use apache commons `ListUtils`

```
ListUtils.union(existingIDS ,newIDSToWrite );
```

You can find the documentation [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/ListUtils.html#union%28java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29).

For the second part of the question you can use the same logic as the question you has asked earlier but a little modification

[delete intersecting values in an arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870714/delete-intersecting-values-in-an-arraylist)

1. (1, 3) (2, 4) (5, 6)
2. curmax = -inf
3. curmax = 3
4. 2 < 3 - mark first and second as "bad". curmax = 4
5. Update value of 2 to (3+1)
6. 5 > 4 - do nothing. curmax = 6.
7. (5,6) - is the only good segment.

Comment: Yes OP has asked a similar question yesterday. A slight modification in the accepted answers logic would achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend something like this (note that it may not compile directly since I wrote it quickly). This code basically makes your class more object oriented and requires the object be initialized with a valid id. As other mentioned above, you must implement hashCode() and equals() to be able to properly compare objects and check if an object is contained within a collection (I usually have eclipse generate these functions for me upon selecting fields):

```
public class IDS {
    private String id;
    private long startTime;
    private long endTime;
    public IDS(String id){
      if(id == null) throw new Exception("RAII failure: IDS requires non-null ID");
      this.id = id;
    }
    // id - getter
    // startTime, endTime - getters/setters

    public boolean equals(IDS otherId){
      if(otherId == null) return false;
      return otherId.getId().equals(getId());
    }
}

List<IDS> existingIDS = new ArrayList<IDS>(); 
List<IDS> newIDSToWrite = new ArrayList<IDS>();

Set<IDS> mergedIds = new HashSet<IDS>(newIDSToWrite);
for(IDS id : existingIDS){
  if(!mergedIds.contains(id)) mergedIds.add(id);
}
```